# Extracting words next to a location or Duration in python

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk

How can i extract words next to a location or Duration? What is the best possible regex in python to do this action?

Example:-

Kathick Kumar, Bangalore who was a great person and lived from 29th March 1980 - 21 Dec 2014.

In the above example i want to extract the words before location and the words before duration. Here the location and duration is not fixed, what will be the best possible regex for this in python? Or can we do this using nltk?

Desired output:-

Output-1: Karthick Kumar (Keyword here is Location)

Output-2: who was a great person and lived from (Keyword here is duration)

Comment: Words before duration meaning before `29th March 1980 - 21 Dec 2014`?
Could you specify the exact output that you need?

Comment: I have specified the desired output

Comment: You could use `Name Entity Recognition` and Chunking/Chinking as on the [link](http://pythonprogramming.net/named-entity-recognition-nltk-tutorial/?completed=/chinking-nltk-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [**Lookaheads**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

In your example, assuming you want the words before *Bangalore* and *29th March 1980 - 21 Dec 2014*, you could use lookaheads( and lookbehinds) to get the relevant match.

I've used this regex: `(.*)(?>Bangalore)(.+)(?=29th March 1980 - 21 Dec 2014)` and captured the text in parentheses, which can be accessed by using `\1` and `\2`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oW2uD1/1)

Comment: This is cool if the location and duration is standard. But my concern is neither the location nor the duration are standard, it keeps changing. In this case what should i do?

Comment: In that case I suggest creating an alternation, `|`, in the atomic grouping with all possible locations like `(?>Bangalore|Hyderabad|..)`, can't think of another way. For the duration you could build another regex, something like `(([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (Jan|Feb|..) [0-2][0-9]{3})'